# Split string and then remove space and number

Tags: jquery

I have these values that come from a php mysqli query.

```
Lobby 26, Noord-Brabant 8, Groningen 0, Friesland 12, Gelderland 28, Limburg 28, Zeeland 0, Overijssel 0, Drenthe 0, Noord-Holland 64, Zuid-Holland 0, Utrecht 14, Belgie 0
```

Let's say that the above is within `str`

```
var foo = str.split(,);
```

`foo[3]` would then give back `Friesland 12` etc.

What i want is to remove the space and number from the split result.

How can i do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget about jQuery and use pure JavaScript...

```
var str = "Lobby 26, Noord-Brabant 8, Groningen 0, Friesland 12, Gelderland 28, Limburg 28, Zeeland 0, Overijssel 0, Drenthe 0, Noord-Holland 64, Zuid-Holland 0, Utrecht 14, Belgie 0";
var foo = str.split(',');

// Removes all spaces and digits
var bar = foo[3].replace(/[ 0-9]/g, '');

// Alternative: remove the first space followed by digits
var bar = foo[3].replace(/ [0-9]*/, '');
```

Comment: @ingridsede why not use array? `var country = str.trim().replace(/[ 0-9]/g, '').split(',');`

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery required here, you can split by the space and only return the first element:

```
var bar = foo[3].split(' ')[0]; // = 'Friesland'
```

Comment: What if this is my string `foo, soo ,ddd, asd `.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest you split by a Regex which can handle the inconsistent spaces and comma placing, like this https://jsfiddle.net/55o3gcco/

Comment: Well that can't be done. As my user have no idea that I will be facing problems due to the spaces he/she is adding in between. All they need to worry about is comma separated string.

Comment: Great I also found just like yours. But yours is better as it handles everything in one-line :).

Answer (score 0):

You can again split the result using below and get the first string

```
 foo[3].split(/ +/)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove space and number is enough to do split and use last index of space.

For example...

var str = "Lobby 26, Noord-Brabant 8, Groningen 0, Friesland 12, Gelderland 28, Limburg 28, Zeeland 0, Overijssel 0, Drenthe 0, Noord-Holland 64, Zuid-Holland 0, Utrecht 14, Belgie 0";

var foo = str.split(', '); //comma+space

At this time you will have an array like this:

```
 var foo = ["Lobby 26", "Noord-Brabant 8", "Groningen 0", "Friesland 12", etc etc];
```

So to remove all final spaces and numbers:

```
 for(var i=0; i<foo.length; i++){
    var lastSpace=foo[i].lastIndexOf(" ");
    foo[i]=foo[i].substring(0, lastSpace);
 }
```

The final result will be:

```
 var foo = ["Lobby", "Noord-Brabant", "Groningen", "Friesland", etc etc];
```

Hopefully this comment will help you... Bye